# Open XML word document - find highlighted text

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, openxml

I have word document, where every paragraph is a very long line.
Something like:

```
"NameOfSomeSort     ----ASDdASFA---F-TEXT-FASFASFAS----FASFASF"
```

characters

```
"TEXT"
```

are being highlighted.
I need to be able to tell, which characters in line are highlited and get their position index in the line.

I was able to do it via Interoop, but the operation will take cca 5-10 hours to go through whole document. So I tried OpenXML, but I'm not able to get text properties like Highlight when I cycle through paragraphs texts.

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: covert office document to .zip file and read about word processingML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight is applied to the run (in runProperties)
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.highlight(v=office.14).aspx)

if your text is "aaaaa [i am highlight] bbbb" the openxml will look like

```
<w:Paragraph>
  <w:Run><w:Text>aaaaa</w:Text></w:Run>
  <w:Run>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:highlight w:val="yellow" />
    </w:rPr>
    <w:Text>[i am highlight]</w:Text>
  </w:Run>
  <w:Run><w:Text>bbbb</w:Text></w:Run>  
</w:Paragraph>
```

So, to find wich text is highlight you have to search for the highlight tag
with something like `Paragraph.Descendants<Highlight>()`

If you need to retrieve the position you can use some algorithm like

```
// Suppose you have the paragraph p you want to inspec and the run r containing highlight
int pos = 0;
OpenXmlElement oxe = null;
// From the run search for the parent (Paragraph p)
// Add the length of previous text in pos
while ((oxe = r.previousSibling()) != p)
{
  pos += ((Run)oxe).Innertext.Length;
}
// here pos should return where the highlight begin (maybe it's pos+1...)
```